# Automate Visio online(O365) to create diagram base on our data

Tags: powershell, office365, diagram, visio, office-automation

I am new to PowerShell and i am attempting to do some automation in Visio(O365) using PowerShell.

I need the code to open a blank page for me and create a diagram based on my data file in excel.
i googled and found the below code but that is not ganna work for O365.

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$documents = $application.Documents
$document = $documents.Add(“NewDrawing.vst”)
$pages = $application.ActiveDocument.Pages
$page = $pages.Item(1)
$stencil = $application.Documents.Add(“Basic Shape.vss”)
$item = $stencil.Masters.Item(“Square”)
$shape = $page.Drop($item, 1.0, 10.6)
$shape.Text = “This is some text.”
$document.SaveAs(“C:fsoMyDrawing.vsd”)
$application.Quit()
```

i know i need to connect to MSOnline first using `Connect-MsolService` but i don't know how to call visio online. Can someone please help me?

Comment: `create a diagram based on my data file in excel` - Unclear description! **IMHO** Task is very untrivial

Comment: You mean Visio Plan 2 or web-based Visio Plan 1? Please describe which Excel's data you have?

Comment: Check the c# documenation for Visio.  Powershell is written in c# and any c# code can be converted to PS.

Comment: @Surrogate i have a table in excel, i need to create a diagram in visio based on that table. Visio plan is not my concern at this point

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for that info, i will check the c# instead. Does any online convertor available to convert from c# to PowerShell?

Comment: Not that I know.  Your code is already mostly c# and not true PS.

Answer (score 1):

Please try [Data Visualizer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-visualizer-diagram-17211b46-d144-4ca2-9ea7-b0f48f0ae0a6) feature!
[image: Visio-Excel]

May be you dont need write any code...

Comment: Thank you @surrogate for introducing this, i didn't know this feature but unfortunately our company doesn't have visio plan 1 or 2 license

Comment: actually, we bought visio plan 2 but the feature doesn't have the ability to create a network diagram based on my excel sheet.

Comment: May be [Network Design Automation](https://ndat.gitbook.io/) can helps?